How to configure serilog with json to write in two different files?
I would like to have a log for information and warning and another log to error and fatal.
I would like to use json file and not fluent API, and use only json, because I have read there is problem getting part of the configuration from json and another part from fluent API.
But I have the problem that in both files it is written all the logs, not only information and warning in one file and error and fatal logs in the other.
I have see this question, but it doesn't use json file.
My program.cs file is this:
builder.Services
    .AddSerilog()
    .AddHostedService<Worker>()
    .InstalarServicios(builder.Configuration);


Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .CreateLogger();

And this is my json file:
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },

    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "LogEventLevel": "Information, Warning",
          "path": "./logs/log-informacion-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      },

      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "LogEventLevel": "Error, Fatal",
          "path": "./logs/log-errores-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

In the json file, I have tried to use "RestrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information" for one file and "RestrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error" for the second, but the result is always the same, it creates two files and in both it writes the same log, no matter if it information or error.
How could I write only in one file information and warning and in the other error and fatal logs?
Thanks.

It seems you are trying to filter your logs then write these filtered logs into distinct files as I can see in your linked example.
You may try this configuration settings inside json file:
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Filters.Expressions" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "Level = 'Information' or Level = 'Warning'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "./logs/log-informacion-.txt",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "Level = 'Error' or Level = 'Fatal'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "./logs/log-errores-.txt",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


In this configuration, distinct filtering and writing into different files inside every logger can be seen.

Thanks for the answer. But in this way still is written all the logs in both files, in the information is written errors too and in the errors are written information logs.

@ÁlvaroGarcía Can you try this one I removed @ inside expressions that might serilog can not configure @ Level  inside expressions

Thanks. It works. But perhaps you could show the complete .json file, to see that it is needed to use "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Filters.Expressions" ],. But thanks so much for the solution.

@ÁlvaroGarcía You're welcome :), I just added "Using" section thank you for your feedback.

To separate logs into two different files i.e. information & warning we can use 2 approaches:

CS Sub-Logging
Using Serilog.Sinks.Map package(make sure you install the package beforehand)
Sntax for the two will be somewhat similar to as follows:

Sub-Logging:
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.Logger(c => c.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug)
        .WriteTo.File("Debug.log"))
    .WriteTo.Logger(c => c.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error)
        .WriteTo.File("Error.log"))
    .CreateLogger();

Serilog.Sinks.Map package:
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.Map(evt => evt.Level, (level, wt) => wt.File($"{level}.log"))
    .CreateLogger();

Edit the above Code as per your requirement; and you'll be able to implement it very easily.

Thanks for the suggestion. But I would prefer to set the configuration in an external configuration file, in this case a .json file, instead to set it in the code. In t his way, I don't need to compile the project again if I need to change the configuration.
